# You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'reason_pct' with dtype float and shape [?,1]

Tags: python, tensorflow

tensorflow version=1.13.1

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ["serve"], "new_model")         
    reason_pct=sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('reason_pct')
    output=sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('output')

    scores = sess.run([output, seven_class], feed_dict={
             reason_pct:np.reshape(0.8,(1,1))}
print(output.eval())
```

but actually,i've passed a float value to variable reason_pct,now i can't figure out how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

solved!the reason is that:i should replace print(output.eval()) with print(scores)